# Trying to fill a SVG with CSS, but not working

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm trying to fill a twitter icon SVG with it's color through CSS. I did this before, I did this in some other places but, for some reason, it stopped working.

Here's the CSS code:

```
.svg path {
fill: #55acee;
}
```

And here's the HTML:

```
<img title="Twitter" class="svg" src="data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='512.002' height='512.002' viewBox='0 0 512.002 512.002'%3E%3Cpath d='M512.002 97.21c-18.84 8.355-39.082 14.002-60.33 16.54 21.686-13 38.342-33.584 46.186-58.114-20.3 12.04-42.777 20.78-66.705 25.49-19.16-20.415-46.46-33.17-76.674-33.17-58.012 0-105.043 47.03-105.043 105.04 0 8.232.93 16.25 2.72 23.938-87.3-4.382-164.7-46.2-216.51-109.753-9.04 15.515-14.222 33.56-14.222 52.81 0 36.444 18.544 68.596 46.73 87.433-17.22-.546-33.416-5.27-47.577-13.14-.01.44-.01.88-.01 1.322 0 50.894 36.21 93.348 84.26 103-8.812 2.4-18.093 3.687-27.673 3.687-6.77 0-13.35-.66-19.764-1.888 13.37 41.73 52.16 72.104 98.127 72.95-35.95 28.175-81.243 44.966-130.458 44.966-8.48 0-16.84-.496-25.06-1.47 46.487 29.806 101.702 47.196 161.022 47.196 193.21 0 298.868-160.062 298.868-298.872 0-4.554-.104-9.084-.305-13.59 20.526-14.81 38.335-33.31 52.417-54.373z' fill='%23FFF'/%3E%3C/svg%3E">
```

I'm pretty sure I'm missing something, but... What is it?
Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/v4jw615q/

Comment: The img tag does not hold any decendants. Which is why your CSS doesn't work.

Comment: I don't think you can style it with css when setting the svg data as a `src` attribute, you have to embed the `<svg>` content directly

Answer (score 6):

Don't make it a `src` of an image, embed it directly

```css
.svg path {
 fill: red !important;
}
```

```html
    
<svg class='svg'
xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='512.002' height='512.002' viewBox='0 0 512.002 512.002'>
<path d='M512.002 97.21c-18.84 8.355-39.082 14.002-60.33 16.54 21.686-13 38.342-33.584 46.186-58.114-20.3 12.04-42.777 20.78-66.705 25.49-19.16-20.415-46.46-33.17-76.674-33.17-58.012 0-105.043 47.03-105.043 105.04 0 8.232.93 16.25 2.72 23.938-87.3-4.382-164.7-46.2-216.51-109.753-9.04 15.515-14.222 33.56-14.222 52.81 0 36.444 18.544 68.596 46.73 87.433-17.22-.546-33.416-5.27-47.577-13.14-.01.44-.01.88-.01 1.322 0 50.894 36.21 93.348 84.26 103-8.812 2.4-18.093 3.687-27.673 3.687-6.77 0-13.35-.66-19.764-1.888 13.37 41.73 52.16 72.104 98.127 72.95-35.95 28.175-81.243 44.966-130.458 44.966-8.48 0-16.84-.496-25.06-1.47 46.487 29.806 101.702 47.196 161.022 47.196 193.21 0 298.868-160.062 298.868-298.872 0-4.554-.104-9.084-.305-13.59 20.526-14.81 38.335-33.31 52.417-54.373z' fill='#FFF'/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 3):

When there is "fill" attribute in "path" element, you can not control SVG style in external CSS file. So:

- (embed the svg code)
- delete "fill" attribute in "path"
- add your style to your CSS file (which now can be directly applied to
  the svg element itself).

> before using "!important", ask yourself: why I have to use this? I'm
> sure you will find a logical way to not doing that. It's important to
> know the reasons in coding.